# Keycloak Synch Registered users into local db

Tags: synchronization, keycloak, user-registration, local-database

I am thinking of using Keycloak to handle authentication & authorisation of my application. So all the details of roles & users will be stored in keycloak. But I also need to have Users in my local database so I can link this to other tables of the application. Whenever a new user gets registered (using keycloak registration page, so data will be stored in keycloak-db) or edit his/her details - then I should create/edit user table in my local database. How can we do this, can we acheive this using keycloak evnt listener ? Please pass on any docs that has info of how we achieve this.

Comment: I actually have the same issue, how did you approach this problem eventually ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71048265/with-sso-like-for-example-keycloak-how-does-one-handle-synchronise-users-in-o here you can find some more details