# How to Sync keycloak users( after Sync of users from AD into keycloak) periodically into our custom database?

Tags: synchronization, single-sign-on, keycloak, event-listener

Problem Statement:
We have a AD with many user, and have configured the User Federation(LADP) in keycloak console to Sync the users from AD to keycloak. How to Sync these users from keycloak to our custom database using any event provider in keycloak? If there is way, how to package thecode and deploy the changed code to the keycloak server and also debug the same code.

As suggested here : [With SSO (like for example Keycloak), how does one handle/synchronise users in own databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71048265/with-sso-like-for-example-keycloak-how-does-one-handle-synchronise-users-in-o)

is this the only way out for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Create custom User Provider SPI and implement *ImportSynchronization inteface*

Comment: Hi Soheli Babadi, we want to Achieve the same in C#. Everywhere we see the solution in Java. Is there a way in C# to implement the same? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I found some helpful information in https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/server_development/topics/user-storage/import.html

Comment: I found this article https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/17507